# Zoom does not work when mouse pointer is over a "div" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, three.js

I have a **threejs** (i.e webgl) viewer, on which I render simple 2D icons as **div elements**

I handle "wheel" event to **zoomin/zoomout** over my models similar to what trackballcontrols does in the original source code and it does work fine except for **one case**.

*This case is when my mouse is hovering over one of these 2D div elements the "wheel" event never reaches the threejs viewer and zoom does not take place*

Is there a **default "wheel" event handler** for a div element and if not what could be the issue?

**Edit:**

I found that **"pointer-events: none"** is one part of solution for this problem but it also removed the click property from this div element. How do we solve it?

Comment: Without any code or page organization, it's quite complicated to answer... Could you provide more informations?

Comment: Please check the "edit" part on this question

Comment: How do you render div elements?

Comment: Can you also share your HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a three.js issue, and more of a raw HTML/JavaScript problem.

You can force the `wheel` event to pass through by creating and dispatching a new event.

Consider the yellow `div` is your three.js `canvas`, and the green `div` is your "floating" `div`.

```html
<div id="outer" style="border: 1px black solid; background: yellow; width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 50px; position: relative;">
 &nbsp;
</div>

<div id="inner" style="border: 1px black solid; background: green; width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 50px; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">
 &nbsp;
</div>

<script>
 var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
 var inner = document.getElementById("inner");

 outer.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
  console.log("outer wheel event on ", e.currentTarget.id);
 });

 inner.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
  var evt = new MouseEvent("wheel", {
   view: window,
   bubbles: true,
   cancelable: true
  });
  outer.dispatchEvent(evt);
  console.log("inner wheel event on ", e.currentTarget.id);
 });
</script>
```

You'll need to fill in some of the blanks to ensure the proper information is sent to the `TrackballControls` events, such as the wheel delta. Take a peek at the `TrackballControls` code to see what event properties it uses for the `wheel` events.

Comment: This helped me solve the issue. Although, for this question i did something like this evt= new WheelEvent(old_event.type, old_event)